# Generate date from week number in moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, dayofweek, momentjs

As mentioned in the title, I have a week number and a year value. Is there a way of finding Monday of that week using moment.js? Was trying, but not succeeded

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Sorry found solution myself:

```
var test = moment().day("Monday").week(week number here);
```

Comment: How to get the date from a week number for a particular year? Thanks

Comment: You would probably use moment().year(2014).week(weeknum);

Comment: To get the beginning of the week use: moment().year(2018).week(25).day('monday').format('MMMM Do YYYY');

Answer (score 21):

Building off the answers provided here...

```
exports.getDateFromWeek = function(week, year) {
    return moment().day("Monday").year(year).week(week).toDate();
};
```

Personally, I wanted the first Sunday... and in which case it's:

```
exports.getDateFromWeek = function(week, year) {
    return moment().day("Sunday").year(year).week(week).toDate();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:-

```
var weekdate= function(year, week, dayNumber)
{
    var j1 = new Date( year,0,10,12,0,0),
        j2 = new Date( year,0,4,12,0,0),
        mon1 = j2.getTime() - j1.getDay() * 86400000;
    return new Date(mon1 + ((week- 1)  * 7  + dayNumber) * 86400000);
};
console.log(weekdate(2010, 1, 4));
```

`2010` starts with `Thursady`

Comment: The OP asked for a solution using Moment.js. As far as I can tell, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
moment('2021').add(16, 'weeks').startOf('week').format('DD MM YYYY');
```

Starts on Sunday. The above code result is "18 04 2021"

```
moment('2021').add(16, 'weeks').startOf('isoweek').format('DD MM YYYY');
```

Starts on Monday. The above code result is "19 04 2021"